# custom constructor use lombok in java

Tags: java, lombok

How can I custom constructor use lombok in java.

**Code:**

```
public class Bean {

    private List<Integer> list;

    public Bean(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    public Bean(Integer... array) {
        this(Arrays.asList(array));
    }

    public void setList(Integer... array) {
        this.list = Arrays.asList(array);
    }
}
```

The first constructor can use `@Builder` and `@Singular` to achieve a similar effect.
But how should the second constructor or method `setList` (like this with other logic) be implemented?